# Triggers in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a control with label.. And a boolean dependency property "IsLink"... So, if IsLink = true, I need to make blue Foreground and Cursor as "Hand" as well..

I can make it with bindings, but in this case I need to write two Converters (BoolToCursor and BoolToForeground), but I'm too lazy for that :)

So, I've tryed smth like that:

```
<Label Name="lblContent" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger SourceName="myControl" Property="IsLink" Value="True">
                     <!--Set properties here-->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
    label's text
</Label>
```

But it doesn't work... Any ideas, gentlemens? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a DataTrigger instead of Normal Trigger.Check the code below

**XAML**

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <Label Name="lblContent" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14">
                <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsLink}"
                                                          Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Label.Style>
                label's text
            </Label>

        </Grid>
    </Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }


        public Boolean IsLink
        {
            get { return (Boolean)GetValue(IsLinkProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsLinkProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLinkProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsLink", typeof(Boolean),
            typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));


    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But one more similar question, if I have two labels and I'd like to hide one label if another's Content is null, I've tried like this but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

```
<CheckBox x:Name="IsLink">IsLink</CheckBox>
<Label Name="lblContent"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="14">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=IsLink, Path=IsChecked}"
                                Value="true">

                    <Setter Property="Label.Foreground"
                            Value="Blue" />
                    <Setter Property="Label.Cursor"
                            Value="Hand" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
    label's text
</Label>
```